# Display user profile_name knowing user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have added an updated_by attribute to my guideline model which stores the user_id of the person who updated the guideline.  I'd like to display this in my show view as the profile_name of the person who updated_by

in guidelines_controller.rb:

```
def update

    @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:id])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @guideline.update_attributes(params[:guideline])
        @guideline.update_attribute(:updated_by, current_user.id)
```

This seems to work fine and allocated the current user's id to updated_by.

```
def show

    @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:id])
    @created = @user.where(:id=>@guideline.updated_by).first.profile_name
```

Then my show view

```
<%= @created %>
```

The error is

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `where' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/guidelines_controller.rb:137:in `show'
```

How can I get the profile name from the updated_by id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
@created = @user.where(:id=>@guideline.updated_by).first.profile_name
```

should read:

```
@created = User.where(:id=>@guideline.updated_by).first.profile_name
```

`where` is a class method on the `User` model. `@user` (usually) refers to an instance of a user, which you haven't instantiated yet, in this case. (It is `nil`; that's why you're getting the `NilClassError`.)

An even cleaner version of this line would be:

```
@created = User.find(@guildeline.updated_by).profile_name
```

Since `User.find` finds the user for a given user_id.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the finder as a class method rather than an object method.

```
@created = User.where(:id => @guideline.updated_by ).first.profile_name
```

Or cleaner

```
@created = User.find(@guideline.updated_by).profile_name
```

It's also possible you may need to search by `@guideline.updated_by.id` instead of  `@guideline.updated_by`. In that case it would be:

```
@created = User.find(@guideline.updated_by.id).profile_name
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the fact that you call where on @user, not on User. Just call

```
@created = User.where(:id=>@guideline.updated_by).first.profile_name
```

Not sure if that's the only problem, but let's deal with them one-by-one.